# cannot get p class=info <span> tag data from beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Cannot get the tag data, cannot get p class=info  tag data from beautifulsoup thanks !

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import re

html = """"
<p class="info">
<span>Kranji Mile Day simulcast races, 
Kranji Racecourse, SIN</span>
<span>Class 3 Handicap   -  1200M TURF</span>
<span>Saturday, 26 May 2018</span>
<span>Race 1, 5:15 PM</span>
</p>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('p', attrs={class:'info'})
rows = table.findAll("span")

print rows
```

expected output seperate by commas

```
Kranji Mile Day simulcast races, Kranji Racecourse, SIN , Class 3, Handicap, 1200M, TURF, Saturday, 26 May 2018, Race 1, 5:15PM
```

Comment: it is class_ bcos class is reserved keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you resolve the `class` problem, as explained in the other answer, you still have to extract strings from the tags:

```
result = ', '.join(r.string for r in rows)
print(result)
#Kranji Mile Day simulcast races, 
# Kranji Racecourse, SIN, Class 3 Handicap   -  1200M TURF, Saturday, 26 May 2018, Race 1, 5:15 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

it is `class_` because class is reserved keyword

```
table = soup.find('p', attrs={'class':'info'})

table = soup.find('p',class_='info'})
```

> Use text attribute it concatenates all text inside the tag
>
> string attribute will not working if it contains another tag inside it

```
print (', '.join(i.text for i in rows)) # For getting text
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm - in python3 this works fine for me if you just quote 'class' in this line

```
table = soup.find('p', attrs={'class':'info'})
                          ^
```

though the output will be the ... elements rather than just the text.  Do you want the elements or only the text?